# visual studio code can't find my python module i've installes with pip

Tags: python, module

this might be a very stupid question but I'm a beginner.

I want to use this package called colorgram, it's a module that extracts colours from images, and I installed it using pip via the CMD. but when I try to import it in VS code it can't find it and I don't know what to do, please help

Comment: Can you provide more details: 

0) your OS? 

1) how do you run your python file in VS code?

2) can you import this package running python in CMD?

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andrii Zadaianchuk

sorry, I'm using windows 10. I tried to import it in python in the CMD but nothing either, just the same ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorgram' error.

I did just notice that the modules python version is 3.5 and VS code is running 3.9.2. I think that  might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

To access the `colorgram` package, your coding file must be on the same hard drive. So let us say that your `colorgram` module is located in `C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\Local\Programs` and you will also see a python folder in the Programs folder, so you must have your coding folder in the Programs folders. And by doing so you are giving your coding folder a more direct path to the `colorgram` module.